# require of casting in Byte and Short

Tags: java, casting

```
Byte byte1=new Byte((byte) 20);
Short short1=new Short((short) 20);
```

why i am bound to use cast operator in Byte and Short but i am not using cast operator in other DataType

```
Integer integer=new Integer(20);
Long long1=new Long(20);
Double double1=new Double(20);
Float float1=new Float(20);
```

Comment: As an aside, there is almost never a case where you want to use `new Byte(...)` instead of `Byte.valueOf(...)`.  The latter caches every value of byte so that it never has to create a new object.  The same goes for all of the other primitive wrapper types, some of which also do caching.

Answer (score 9):

It's because the second snippet results in widening primitive conversions in accordance with [JLS §5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - `byte` to `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `short` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `char` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `long` to `float` or `double`
> - `float` to `double`

Whereas the first does not; notice that there is no conversion from `int` to `short` or `byte`.

Answer (score 2):

The literal "20" is handled as an *int* by the compiler. 
*Integer*, *Long*, *Float* and *Double* can handle number ranges which are greater or equal than the range of *int* so the compiler can do an implizit cast. *Short* and *Byte* do have smaller ranges which prevents implizit casts. Casting explizitly may result in a *ClassCastException* if the number is not representable by *Byte* or *Short*.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for [`Byte`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#Byte%28byte%29) requires a `byte` if you're constructing it like that, and the same is true for the constructor of [`Short`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#Short%28short%29).

Numbers without a cast or a type literal are always seen as `int`.

Comment: Well, the constructor of `Long` expects a `long` (same goes for `Double` and `Float`), but his second snippet still compiles.

Comment: This is adequately explained by your answer, you know this.  Widening does occur from int and above, but not to short and below.

Answer (score 0):

The Constructor of byte is defined as

```
 public Byte(byte value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
```

It expects byte , since you are passing integer you need to cast explicitly, Same holds true for short

Comment: Well, the constructor of `Long` expects a `long`, but his second snippet still compiles.

Comment: adding to some more info to my post  Downcasting needs to be done explicitly while upcasting  will be done implicitly

Comment: converting int to byte and short is downcasting, while converting  integer to float,double,long is upcasting

Answer (score 0):

```
Byte byte1=new Byte((byte) 20);
```

> The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

But, 20 above is an integer.

> The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647
>   (inclusive).

So, *byte* cannot take any value out of the range. You will lose data (bits) when you try assigning an integer say *130* rather than *20* because *130* is out of *byte* range. By casting you are telling the compiler that you are aware of the conversion.